# ajax comparing changes, if there are changes then it will update

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, setinterval

i want to make a review within my code, i am making a JavaScript/ajax code that will run every sec. Now here is what my code does,
It will check if there are changes in the queue, if there is changes, then it will alert, if there were no changes, then it will continue running to always check, now why is it sometimes it will alert and sometimes it will not alert. Here is my code:

```
function check_getqueue(clinicID, userID) {
var tmpCountQ = [];
  $.ajax({
    url: siteurl+"sec_myclinic/checkingUpdates/"+clinicID+"/"+userID,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
      for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        tmpCountQ.push(data[i]['queue_id']);
      };
      if(typeof lastCon[0] != "undefined")
      {
        for(j=0;j < tmpCountQ.length;j++)
        {
          if(tmpCountQ[j] != lastCon[j])
          {
            $("#boxqueue").empty();
            alert("there is change");
            // refresh_afterdel(clinicID, userID);
            lastCon[j] = tmpCountQ[j];
          } 
        } 
      }
      else
      {
       lastCon = tmpCountQ;
      }
      // console.log("lastCon "+lastCon)
      // console.log("tmpCountQ "+tmpCountQ);
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

variable `j` is not initialised. So it may be updating the same global `j`

```
function check_getqueue(clinicID, userID) {
var tmpCountQ = [];
  $.ajax({
    url: siteurl+"sec_myclinic/checkingUpdates/"+clinicID+"/"+userID,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
      for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        tmpCountQ.push(data[i]['queue_id']);
      };
      if(typeof lastCon[0] != "undefined")
      {
        for(var j=0;j < tmpCountQ.length;j++)
        {
          if(tmpCountQ[j] != lastCon[j])
          {
            $("#boxqueue").empty();
            alert("there is change");
            // refresh_afterdel(clinicID, userID);
            lastCon[j] = tmpCountQ[j];
          } 
        } 
      }
      else
      {
       lastCon = tmpCountQ;
      }
      // console.log("lastCon "+lastCon)
      // console.log("tmpCountQ "+tmpCountQ);
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: did you try this?

Comment: hello sir, now i've figured out my problem, the situation is this,
First, the lastCon and tmpCountQ has no values, then if i add values for example 1, then they have all 1 values, so the condition if(tmpCountQ[j] != lastCon[j]) will not satisfy, how can i edit this?

Answer (score -1):

You are not guaranteed synchronous calls to the server and all variables not declared in the success or error functions as local vars are therefore not guaranteed to be fifo which is what a queue demands. The solution is to use a buffer with package sequence numbers to organize the data into a fifo queue. This means changing what is returned into a JSON array of JSON objects with an integer id. When checking the data make sure you have seen the correct packets before alerting. When you have the next packet alert and repeat until the server's queue is empty.

Comment: You can mark me down 1 but I am saying you do not understand concurrency so go ahead make me -1 but that's the truth. You need a hand shake to ensure concurrency over an asynchronous system with multiple threading talking to a ajax call.